# Вывод баланса пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Мне необходимо на каждой странице выводить баланс пользователя. Накладно будет обращаться каждый раз к базе. Я бы хотел, при выводе баланса к базе обращаться один раз в 5 минут. ( чтобы данные заносить  во временную таблицу ). Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Можно этот самый баланс писать в пользовательскую сессию.

Comment: А что сложного? Один раз записать баланс который хранится в БД, в куку и установить время жизни 5 минут!

Comment: Понял. Мне нужно проверить существует ли переменная $_COOKIE['balance'], если не существует - то обращаемся к базе (а после обращения записываем данные в куку); если существует - то выводим её. 
Я Вас правильно понял?

Comment: Правильно.

Comment: Динамическое обновление. AJAX/PHP
Поищи в интернете, там много такого, а лучше все же да, через кэш

Answer (score 2):

Офтоп но все же скажу.
А зачем нужно 1 раз в 5 минут запрашивать баланс с базы?
Я бы сделал по другому - значение баланса кэшировал бы. Далее определяем список действий которые меняют значение баланса- и соответственно по ним перезаписываем кэшь.
как то так